# Angular - Jasmine : how to check if a field has focus on it

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am setting focus on a field via below code in angular component file :

```
this.renderer.selectRootElement('#userId').focus();
```

Same I want to test using Jasmine 
something like this I have tried but not working :

```
expect(component.form.get('user').focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
```